# json.encode() give empty result

Tags: javascript, c#, json

To make google charts, I'm using a list of this model:

```
public class GraphEmployee
{
        string month;
        List<int> values;
        ...
}
```

When I try to `Json.encode(List<GraphEmployee)`, I've got the right number of elements but it's all empty like this : `[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]`

Is `Json.encode()` not capable of encode my model or did I have to do something special ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Well do you have anything *public* for it to encode? Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: Class fields are private by default. Change your fields to public.

Comment: @Robear Ok I thought it was the opposite ! Thank you !

Comment: @JonSkeet I tought attributes were public by default ^^'  Thank you !

Comment: Note: it's a bad idea to make the fields themselves public. Expose properties instead. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes sure ! I will check that ;) Thank you